# Windows 7 laptop no longer sees USB drives - how to fix?

Tags: windows-7, usb, usb-flash-drive

When I plug USB drives in to my computer the icon on lower right shows that a USB device is ready to use, but Windows 7 does not show the drive anywhere. Under Disk Management ([screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMXhh.jpg)) I see the USB drive as disk 1, but choosing assign drive does not work because it keeps telling me "The Operation failed to complete because the Disk Management console view is not up-to-date" No matter what I do I keep getting this message. This happens regardless of USB drive. I do not believe any of the USB sticks have bad data. I don't want to try approaches that wipe the data, reformat, etc. I have tried reinstalling USB drivers, no luck. Also, I should mention that this problem happened after I had a power cable break. I then tried resoldering the broken wire and at one point I saw a little spark on the little circuit board for the power cable (the part right near where the plug plugs into the computer). Then I resoldered again and everything works. So I don't know if this power glitch caused a problem (no USB stick was plugged in at the time) with USB in general, but if anyone has ideas, please let me know.

Note: just plugged one USB drive in other windows computer and works fine. Other shows up as an unformatted drive. Maybe second one shows up that way because it was formatted as a boot/install drive for MAC OS?

Anyway, ideas welcome!

Answer (score 0):

In my little knwoledge to avoid formating windows you can try a live usb linux disk (or any other Operating System), so you can check if it is a hardware problem (the electric discharge may have fried some really sensitive circuit) or just a windows software problem.
When trying to boot from usb (UEFI or BIOS) you'll already know if USB port works.